# Using texreg() in R, how to add a line in generated LaTeX table

Tags: r, texreg

How can I add to a table a (text or empty) line in the middle of a LaTeX tabular environment generated with `texreg()` from a regression result. In the example below, I would like to add the empty line and a line with ***Subtitle for Coefficients Below***. The Coefficients 1 - 4 are from the regression and are selected and sorted using `custom.coef.map =` in `texreg()`.

| Variable | Model 1 |
| --- | --- |
| Coefficient of Variable 1 | 999.99 |
| Coefficient of Variable 2 | 999.99 |
|  |  |
| ***Subtitle for Coefficients Below*** |  |
| Coefficient of Variable 3 | 111.11 |
| Coefficient of Variable 4 | 111.11 |

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the argument `groups = list("Subtitle for coefficients below" = 3:4)` or similar.